# Integration: easy, but how?

Tags: integration

Once again I have to deal with an Integral, which seems to be not that hard:

$ \int x^{n-1} * sin(x^n) dx  $ and $(n \in \mathbb{N})$

Do you have any hint for me ? :)

Comment: $(x^n)'=nx^{n-1}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**: If $u = x^n$, then $$x^{n - 1} dx = \frac{1}{n} du$$

Answer (score 1):

The primitive of 
$$f\left( x\right) =x^{n-1}\sin \left( x^{n}\right)$$
is
$$F\left( x\right) =-\frac{1}{n}\cos \left( x^{n}\right)$$
as you can easily check by calculating the derivative of $F\left( x\right) $.

Answer (score 0):

In this easy case there is no substitution needed.  Just detect the scheme
$$\int \square'\cdot f(\square)=F(\square).$$